# Bullhorn / LinkedIn Integration

Tags: linkedin-api

My company uses the Bullhorn ATS which has a feature to share job information on LinkedIn.  That feature has stopped working (get "Page Not Found" from LinkedIn).  As I feared, Bullhorn said it is a LinkedIn issue, and LinkedIn pointed me here.  So I'm not really sure what I am asking for on this forum other than some guidance on how to get the right people to address this issue. Any insights would be most appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I regret to be the first one to inform you, that unfortunatelly such questions are considered off-topic here. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how SO works.

Comment: My apologies, I was directed here by LinkedIn support.

Comment: I understand that. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292340/5366641) for more information.

Comment: Actually, Stack overflow is a huge knowledge base to learn from and a great place to get help about a large amount of issues. The rules are there in order to keep it like that and I am trully sorry that because of those rules your first experience was not as positive as it should be.